# Como passar um parametro pela URL usando HttpGet em ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core, http-request

tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET CORE 2.0 onde eu fiz o seguinte método no controller `[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index(int idLeilao)
        {
            ConsultaCarrosModel obj = new ConsultaCarrosModel();
            ViewBag.ListaMarcas = obj.ListaMarcas("marcas.json");
            return View();
        }`

Ao clicar em um botão passando essa 'ID' na url ela é carregada com o ID que eu desejo mas o valor que chega no controller é sempre 0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver a ID que passei na URL é 4 mas a que chegou no controller foi 0(default), como se ela não chegasse no controller antes de carregar a página

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar o atributo Route:

```
 [HttpGet("/Home/Index/{idLeilao}")]
 public IActionResult Index(int idLeilao)
 {
     ConsultaCarrosModel obj = new ConsultaCarrosModel();
     ViewBag.ListaMarcas = obj.ListaMarcas("marcas.json");
     return View();
 }
```

[Roteamento para ações do controlador no ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)